# AnyLogic: Correct way to select a dataset from internal database

Tags: database, class, anylogic

In my anylogic-project i query datasets from the internal database. The table i want to query has following structure:

```
Name: product_innovation_level
--------------------------------
ID|level_customer|level_employee|
--|--------------|--------------|
 1|            10|            14|
```

The only example i could find uses the Tuple-class as shown below. It works, but it feels quite clunky that i have to extract  the needed values manually from the item.

```java
Tuple innovationLevel = selectFrom(product_innovation_level).
                        where(product_innovation_level.id.eq(1)).
                        firstResult(product_innovation_level.level_customer, product_innovation_level.level_employee);

double ngEmployee = innovationLevel.get(product_innovation_level.level_employee);
double ngCustomer = innovationLevel.get(product_innovation_level.level_customer);
```

Is there a better way to select the values directly into an model class? I'm looking for something like this:

```java
xxx innovationLevel = selectFrom(product_innovation_level).
                                  where(product_innovation_level.id.eq(1)).
                                  firstResult(xxx);
```

What class i schould use for xxx? I found an automatically created class Qproduct_innovation_level, but i didn't found a way to access the values of this dataset.

```java
Qproduct_innovation_level innovationLevel = selectFrom(product_innovation_level).
                                  where(product_innovation_level.id.eq(1)).
                                  firstResult(product_innovation_level);
int i  = innovationLevel.level_customer.intValue();
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from NumberExpression<Integer> to int
```

I tried to write a model-class on my own, but here i get type-mismatch error (cannot convert from Qproduct_innovation_level to InnovationLevelModel).

Comment: Your second code snippet that is exactly how you do it directly (if you know your query only returns 1 value). What is the problem?

Comment: Hi Benjamin. I extended my question, i don't know whawt class to use respectively how i can access the needed values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my answer may be a bit ridiculous, but maybe it's what you want...

Create a class with the following constructor and variables:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    public double ngEmployee;
    public double ngCustomer;
    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public MyClass(Tuple innovationLevel) {
        this.ngEmployee = innovationLevel.get(product_innovation_level.level_employee);
        this.ngCustomer = innovationLevel.get(product_innovation_level.level_customer);
    }

}
```

And then you can create an instance of that class like this:

```
MyClass mc=new MyClass(selectFrom(product_innovation_level).
                        where(product_innovation_level.id.eq(1)).
                        firstResult(product_innovation_level.level_customer, product_innovation_level.level_employee));
```

Magic... now you can access the variables using `mc.ngEmployee` and `mc.ngCustomer`

Comment: This would centralize the conversation from Tuple to my MyClass, but it's a lot of manual work if i want to do this for all tables. I hoped that there would be some automatic generated methods.

Comment: then you have no option but to use what you are already using

Answer (score 0):

This is where you use AnyLogic's visually-defined auto-creation of agent populations (including the agent type definition) from a database table.

Use the `Agent` wizard (from the top of the Agent palette): by creating a population of a new type, using a database table, AnyLogic will

- Create a new agent type with parameters which match the columns in the table
- Create a population of this agent type with an instance per row (other variants are possible), mapping the columns to the appropriate agent parameters

Thus, in your case, you could have a population `innovationLevels` of agent type `InnovationLevel`, where this agent had parameters

- `id` (type `int`)
- `levelCustomer` (type `int`)
- `levelEmployee` (type `int`)

(and the wizard would auto-define this agent type and its use in a database-table-driven population).

See **AnyLogic Help > Agent Based Modeling > Creating a new agent population based on DB data** in the help.

If your IDs are sequential (e.g., 1,2,3,...) you can also then access a given innovation level by its position in the list (e.g., `innovationLevels(1)` for the second in the list which might be id 2). You can also do things like create a map (using a Collection) of id to `InnovationLevel` if you want to be able to 'randomly access' an innovation level by ID (if the IDs are not sequential).

Other agents could include references to `InnovationLevel` instances as needed.

Comment: In my simulation i create my main-agents from the database as you describe. Further i encapsulated some calculations in seperate classes, here i want to select specific data out of the database. An seperate agent for this data would be a bit overkill in my opinion.

Comment: There is not much overhead in creating an Agent as opposed to a simpler class and, since this looks like classic 'lookup data', it is normal to load it into a data structure at model initialisation (so as to minimise queries and isolate all input data handling / validation into model init). You can also just create a class and then write a few lines of code to query the table and loop through all rows to create the required lookup data structure with those classes.

Comment: By definition, there is a divide between relational DB data and objects (which is why OR-mapping frameworks like Hibernate exist). An OR mapping tool *is* what you use in general to do 'automated' mapping from relational-table-data to objects, and the QueryDSL stuff in AnyLogic isn't doing that / trying to do that.

Comment: ... The auto-creation of agent populations *is* the one way AnyLogic natively goes in this OR-mapping direction.